# Set Minutes in DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

In jQuery are function to set Minutes, Hours etc. Is this also in PHP?

I have:

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

and

```
$min = '23';
```

I would like in $date set minutes to $min.

Is possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [`DateTime::setTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php).

If you want to modify the minutes and leave the hours untouched, you will of course have to pass the current hours value as the first parameter. Get that one with `$dateTime->format('G')`.

Comment: In this function i must enter also hours. I want set only minutes

Comment: @MarkFondy: Then obviously you need to pass in the current hours value so that it will stay unchanged. See the update.

Comment: sow how can i make it in my example?

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime::modify()` would be a start. Just read the documentation found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)